# InfoPath Formula in Rules

Tags: formula, infopath2010

I'm new to writing formulas in infopath and can't see what I'm doing wrong with the following:

```
if (contains(userName(), "\"))
{
substring-after(userName(), "\")
}
else
}
 userName()
}
```

The above is erroring on the first brace

I can write 2 rules to achieve the same thing but would like to use the above approach if it can be done!?

This a form load rule in infoPath 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this which seems to explain it, in case anyone else has the same issue...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/11/27/conditional-default-values.aspx